# Calling Windows Azure Mobile Service from Worker Role

Tags: windows-8

I have a worker process in Windows Azure and I was wondering if I can call Windows Azure Mobile Service from my worker process on the server.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what part of WAMS are you interested in leveraging?  Have you tried and it's not working?

Comment: WAMS provides very easy integration of Push Notificaiton service from the server scripts. I am mainly interested in leveraging that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still looking for this but I found a REST API reference that could work (i haven't used it yet though).
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj710108.aspx